# Cannot turn on sharing on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sharing

After I turn on the slider, nothing happen. When i exit the window and go back to it, it turned off again.
I want to use screen sharing. What do I have to do ?
[image: Image after turn on the slider]

Comment: The  screen sharing is a VNC server, try to install the vino vnc server `sudo apt install vino`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen sharing is featured by Vino vnc server, you just have to install it

```
sudo apt install vino
```

FYI, The ssh server (too) can be enabled/disabled on this gnome settings section