# How to finally launch a VNC server on 18.04 without installing a different desktop?

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I moved one of my desktop to Ubuntu to try it. In **Centos 7**, all I need to do to launch a VNC server and see my desktop remotely is: `yum install tigervnc-server xorg-x11-fonts-Type1` and `vncserver`.
And I can see correctly my desktop as if I was in front of the monitor. No need to modify any `xstartup` file or anything!

**The question comes back again and again without acceptable answer then I have few more:**

1. Why nobody could do it in Ubuntu yet?

   - If Unity or for whatever reason it isn't possible, let me know.
2. Why 99% of the tutorials required us to install xfce?!

   - I don't want to install anything else
     **Finally, for an ultimate time:**
3. Is there a proper way to install a VNC server without modifying `xstartup`, and without installing a tier desktop?

*I don't expect a simple answer here, if you provide a `xstartup` file, I'd like to get all the explanations. No need to get the same what I can read in the hundreds duplicated blogs.*

Comment: `x11vnc -create -env FD_PROG=/usr/bin/unity -env X11VNC_CREATE_GEOM={$1:-800x800x24} -nopw -localhost -forever -shared -noshm`

Comment: Why `x11vnc`? Latest version: 2011. Why is `Xvfb` mandatory here and not in Centos?

Comment: Moreover even after the `x11vnc` and `xvfb` installations, I get lots of `XOpenDisplay`   errors and asking me to run `x11vnc` as root. No way.

Comment: The above line is exactly what I use on my phone. Why don't you `ssh -x`, no need for vnc.

Comment: 1. no need ssh in local 2. ssh X forwarding performance is awful 3. can forward only the app I launched 4. the app closes with the connection 5. using windows?! 6. it isn't my question 7. a lot more

Comment: Oh, you are using Windows? Then you should be either using `ssh -x` with WSL (in Win7 I use Cygwin with XWin) or using Remote Desktop Protocol, also known as RDP. Take a look into this -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely (you can ignore the part that says to install xfce, but you will need to replace the bin for whatever you are using. I tried with KDE and it worked.)

Answer (score 5):

Controlling current desktop currently is a standard feature of Ubuntu
It is called 'desktop sharing'.
VNC server is installed by the `vino` package and his setup available in the `gnome-control-center sharing`

See [Cannot turn on sharing on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123046/cannot-turn-on-sharing-on-ubuntu-18-04/1123156#1123156)

```
sudo apt install vino
gnome-control-center sharing &
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it requires to be already logged in. And it's a concurrent screen sharing. I'm more looking for something like what I can do with Centos, creating one or several independent sessions. Sorry, I misled you in my question. Edited.